# Finding the minimum length such that a sliding window sliding by its full length contains all intervals of a given set

Tags: algorithm

I need to implement a faceted search of products by price, i.e. I'd like to efficiently produce a list of ranges with a count of products that fall within each range.

For various reasons the best thing I can build as an index is a table that for each product gives the minimum and maximum possible price of the product, e.g.:

```
idProduct | priceMin | priceMax
1         | 15       | 20
2         | 2        | 3
3         | 5        | 7
4         | 13       | 19
```

We can assume that all numbers are natural integers.

To make querying efficient, I'd like to find a size `s` such that it is guaranteed that for each product, there exists a natural number k, such as:

```
k * s <= priceMin && priceMax <= (k + 1) * s
```

In other words, pre-compute a list of ranges such that it is easy to determine if a given product falls into one of the ranges.

Using the data above, the number 12 is a suitable value for `s`, because:

```
1 * 12 <= 15 && 20 <= 2 * 12
0 * 12 <= 2 && 3 <= 1 * 12
0 * 12 <= 5 && 7 <= 1 * 12
1 * 12 <= 13 && 19 <= 2 * 12
```

However, the number 6 is not a suitable value for `s` because it doesn't work for product #3 as `0 * 6 <= 5` but `7 > 1 * 6`

In the real world, the price table will have hundreds of thousands of rows so I'm looking for an efficient algorithm that would allow me to find the smallest possible value for `s`.

If this is a classical problem and you know it's name, I can google from there, but so far I wasn't able to find anything related.

Comment: So, you  want the densest lattice that intersects none of the input intervals? That should be doable.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not very familiar with those terms, but probably :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reasonably efficient algorithm (O(n + P log P) where P is the maximum price, assuming integral prices). (I'm concerned that your constraints will make s too large for your liking, but eh.)

Observe (as Jan Dvorak did first) that the condition

```
there exists k such that k * s <= priceMin and priceMax <= (k + 1) * s
```

is equivalent to

```
for all k, it holds that k * s <= priceMin or priceMax <= k * s
```

is equivalent to

```
for all k, it does not hold that priceMin < k * s < priceMax.
```

The proof isn't bad, but I won't bother writing it out.

Step one of the algorithm is to compute the union of the open price intervals `(priceMin, priceMax)` as a bitmap.

```
deltaIntervalCount = [0] * (P + 1)
for priceMin, priceMax in priceIntervals:
    deltaIntervalCount[priceMin + 1] += 1
    deltaIntervalCount[priceMax] -= 1
intervalCount = [0] * (P + 1)
for p in range(1, P + 1):
    intervalCount[p] = intervalCount[p - 1] + deltaIntervalCount[p]
forbidden = [intervalCount[p] > 0 for p in range(P + 1)]
```

Step two of the algorithm is to try candidates for s in increasing order.

```
for s in range(1, P + 1):
    if all(not forbidden[k * s] for k in range(P // s + 1)):
        return s
```

Comment: Curious to see if there isn't a true polynomial algorithm for the problem. But nice solution, anyway :D

Comment: Thanks, nice solution, gonna try it. Come to think of it, wouldn't it be enough to look for s between minS and 2*minS where minS is the maxmal length of priceMax - priceMin? this could be computed during the first pass.

Comment: @djfm That's the rub -- you can get in trouble with even large choices of s if the intervals are aligned the wrong way: 5 to 7 is a difference of 2, yet s = 6 fails.

Comment: Unfortunately you're correct :) Finally got around to testing it, the algorithm should be fast enough for my needs, thanks!